# Git push results in fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up a git repo on my local lan and have so far been able to clone, pull, fetch etc.  Unfortunately, when I attempt to push, it results in

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

The syslog shows:

> git-daemon[10090]: 'receive-pack': service not enabled for './www-dev/aptwebsite.git'

After some research, I thought I could just enable "receive-pack" but I can't figure out how.

When I try:

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

I get:

> fatal: unable to allocate any listen sockets on host (null) port 9418.

When I try

```
git receive-pack <working directory>
```

I get:

> 00700000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{} report-status delete-refs side-band-64k ofs-delta
>   0000^C

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers that may help in case people run into "The remote end hung up unexpectedly" with git-daemon.

1) The [Git "How to" documentation on git-daemon](https://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/howto/use-git-daemon.html) says that the "remote end hung up" message is a generic message. You should look at the server log for more information on what might have gone wrong. For initially getting things set up, I'd also recommend the --informative-errors switch to git-daemon, which will produce a more helpful error to the git push command.

2) The second issue is the "unable to allocate any listen sockets on host (null) port 9418". This is from the code that implements git-daemon, namely [daemon.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/daemon.c#L949). This code has a function socksetup() that generates this error when it has problems setting up the sockets. In other words: this is a network plumbing problem. Make sure there isn't another daemon running with port 9418.

3) [git receive-pack](https://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/git-receive-pack.html) is not meant to be run by the end user. That said, the string "00700000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{} report-status delete-refs side-band-64k ofs-delta" is exactly what you would get if the 'working directory' is a newly initialized Git repo.

In short: check the logs from git-daemon, and pay attention to network plumbing.